# how to store location in Point field using Mongo Engine and fetch nearest 5 restaurant around a location

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine

I am new to mongoengine and trying to store location data into MongoDB using mongoengine , I am doing some silly mistake but not able to figure out.

My requirement is to store location data into MongoDB and fetch all the restaurant a in 1000 Meter radius around a mobile device location

My Model Class

`from mongoengine import *`

`class ResLocation(Document):
    id = IntField(required=True)
    loc = PointField(required=False)
    updated_date_time = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)`

In the views.py saving the location

```
`def store_restra_location(id, lat, lon):
location = {type: "Point", "coordinates": [lat, lon]}
res_location = ResLocation(id=id, loc=location)
res_location.save()`
```

I am a completely noob in dealing with Mongo with mongoengine 
Please provide a solution to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

I am able solve the problem, I have used a library called geojson 
pip install geojson

`from geojson import Point`

For saving

`location = Point((Decimal(lat), Decimal(lon)))`